# Programming the ATMEGA328 chip without an ADRUINO

Tags: atmega

I have the code I can copy and paste, just wondering if I can program the chip with my desktop. I have Windows Vista 64bit. Building what the author states as an Adruino spot welder controller/solid state relay. Just delays a transformer DIY spot welder to a more precise measure.

Thanks!

Comment: What's an 'Adruino'? Is it a bricked Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

To program the chip you need something to program it with. That could be an Arduino that has itself been programmed to be a programmer, or a real hardware programmer like the nice and cheap USB ASP adapter.

Without that kind of thing you have no way of wiring the chip up to your computer.